# Solve the improper integral with techniques of complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

This is an integral classified as "rational function multiplied by a trigonometric function", but I do not see how I could satisfy conditions of Jordan's lemma. Namely, it's obvious that singularities are $x = i$, $x = -i$ and $x = 0$, where all three are $\textit{first order poles}$ (hence, $x = 0$ satisfies conditions for residues $Im(z) > 0$ and $Im(z) = 0$), but what contour should I choose and how do I calculate the integral? Integral is $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {x - \sin x} {x^3(x^2 + 1)}dx.$$ Also, I've searched online for it thoroughly, but I haven't found anything about it. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Am I aloud to do that? Assistant told us we can only calculate "main values" of these integrals and iff singularities over real line are first order poles.

Comment: Actually, I missed the singularity at the origin too. You'll need to add a contour that takes a semicircle around the origin to avoid it; but it's ok, because the numerator vanishes to third order, just like the denominator. The singularity is removable.

Comment: @user296602 There is no singularity at the origin.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos There *is* a singularity at the origin, because of $1/z^3$; but it's a removable one.

Comment: @user296602 All right. I'll rephrase it: there is no non-removable singularity at the origin.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But how do I then solve the integral? I cannot split it as sum, because the integrals I get do have singularities at the origin?

Comment: @user296602 For $x\to 0$ the entire function goes to $1/6$. There is NO singularity at the origin.

Comment: By the way, just for the sake of curiosity. I calculated the integral and the result shall be 

$$\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{e}$$

Comment: Yes, that should be solution. Workbook claims it too. Do you have an advice? For both types, "rational function" and "rational function times trigonometric" we use upper semi-circle of radius R > 0. But I do not see how could that help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about the contour $C_1$ that starts at $z=\frac12$, follows the real axis from there to $z=-\frac12$, and then follows the circle $|z|=\frac12$ counterclockwise back to $z=\frac12$. There are no singularities except for the removable one at $z=0$ within or along the contour, so
$$\oint_{C_1}\frac{z-\sin z}{z^3\left(z^2+1\right)}dz=0$$
Thus if $C_2$ runs form $z=-R$ to $z=R$ along the real axis,
$$\begin{align}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3\left(x^2+1\right)}dx&=\int_{C_2}\frac{z-\sin z}{z^3\left(z^2+1\right)}dz\\
&=\int_{C_2}\frac{z-\sin z}{z^3\left(z^2+1\right)}dz+\int_{C_1}\frac{z-\sin z}{z^3\left(z^2+1\right)}dz\\
&=\int_{C_3}\frac{z-\frac{e^{iz}}{2i}}{z^3\left(z^2+1\right)}dz+\int_{C_3}\frac{\frac{e^{-iz}}{2i}}{z^3\left(z^2+1\right)}dz\end{align}$$
Where $C_3$ runs from $z=-R$ to $z=-\frac12$ along the real axis, from $z=-\frac12$ to $z=\frac12$ along the circle $|z|=\frac12$, and then to $z=R$ along the real axis. We close the first of the integrals above with a semicircle at $|z|=R$, enclosing the poles at $z=0$ and $z=i$ counterclockwise and the second below with a semicircle at $|z|=R$, enclosing the pole at $z=-i$ clockwise, and then take the limit as $R\rightarrow\infty$ of both integrals.

Thus we get $2\pi i$ times the residues at $z=0$ and $z=i$ of the first integrand and $-2\pi i$ times the residue at $z=-i$ of the second integrand.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3\left(x^2+1\right)}dx=2\pi i\left(-\frac34i+\frac i2-\frac{e^{-1}}{4i}\right)-2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{-1}}{4i}\right)=\frac{\pi}2-\frac{\pi}e$$
As in the comment of @Artificial Intelligence above.